# What percentage do specific foods add to the disease risk pool on survival difficulty?

Tags: fallout-4

I would love to know the exact percentage values that each individual food item adds to the Disease Risk Pool (DRP) when playing on the survival difficulty.

The wiki states the following:

> Food always adds +1% to the DRP (but does not force a roll). Foods can also have a low disease risk (+3% to the DRP), standard (+7%), high (+12%), or very high (+20%).

However, I can't seem to find a list/table of each food item with its correlated disease risk. This information would be incredibly helpful in deciding what the best obtainable food source would be.

Comment: As with all wikis, we may need to take the statement with a grain of salt since it cites no source, especially since nobody else seems to talk about disease risk due to food.

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/1639787494957824281/) post is based on the code in the HC manager script itself, and states the following on food:

> Every time you eat an item it adds minimum 1% to your disease risk pool (even if the food is not hazardous) but does not force a roll.
>
> - Drinking most safe drinks (not Dirty Water) adds 0% and does not force a roll
> - Drinking Nuka-Cola adds 2% but does not force a roll.
> - Ingesting certain high risk items triggers a roll as well as increasing your risk pool.
> - Eating normally-risky foods adds 7% to the pool.
> - Eating high risk foods adds 12% to the pool.
> - Cannibalism adds 5% to the pool (same as a monster bite) - human flesh is relatively healthy it seems ;-)

And to answer your question, in [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/1639787494957824281/?ctp=4#c1637536330459570001) the risks associated with each food are listed:

> **Foods with Standard disease risk in raw form** (+7% to pool, immediate check):
>
> - Dirty Water (bottled or pumped)
> - Bloatfly meat (safer than most insects)
> - Blood packs
> - Brahmin meat
> - Cat meat
> - Cave Fungus
> - Pretty much all raw meat / eggs not listed below (I have hand-checked and didn't find any more exceptions)
>
> **Foods with High disease risk in raw form** (+12% to pool, immediate check): :
>
> - Mutant hound meat
> - Glowing blood pack
> - Moldy food
> - Lukowski's potted meat
> - Glowing One meat
> - Ghoul meat (from a specific quest)
> - Bloodbug meat
> - Stingwing meat
> - Radroach meat
> - Molerat meat
>
> **All other foods presumably have the +1% default risk, no immediate check** (except: 0% for Purified Water, 2% Nuka-Cola) Including:
>
> - All prepared or cooked foods not listed above
> - All raw crops and wild plants
> - Pristine Deathclaw Egg
> - Brain Fungus
> - Glowing Fungus
> - Canned Dogfood

If I recall correctly, anything that adds up to below 25% will not trigger a dice roll, above that you might fall sick.

Author: [The Inept European](https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198001503710) (who seems to be far from inept :) )